# pandas - create sparse matrix for collaborative filtering

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| user_id | music_id | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 5 |
| B | a | 3 |

and I would like to create a sparse matrix from it, putting music_id as column and user_id as a row like this:

->

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 |  |
| B | 3 |  |

what would be the way to achieve it by using pandas or numpy for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we suppose you have the following dataset as describe in your question:

```py
d = {'user_id':['A','B'],'music_id':['a','a'],'rating':[5,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then you can do:

```py
df.set_index(['user_id','music_id']).unstack(level=-1).rating
```

or, equivalently:

```py
pd.pivot_table(df,values='rating',index='user_id',columns=['music_id'])
```